# Mobile Adhoc NETwork

Tags: networking, java-me, mobile, bluetooth, adhoc

How to create a Mobile Adhoc NETwork using bluetooth for transmission and j2me for programming? Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by first choosing an API for Bluetooth like Bluecove etc. Google the available APIs that support java and you can choose any one you find better for you. I have personally worked on Bluecove. But i have never created an Adhoc network. I think you need to create a PAN (personal area network) via bluetooth. Please elaborate how you want to use your ad-hoc network so can tell you something more about it.